# I try to get values of -deps but other way

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I edit the question, because I have advanced with the program. It still does not do what I want. So the problem is due to ignorance of Ocaml, the variable `"aux2"` is of type: `"Function_From.Deps.t -> Function_From.Deps.t"`. C How could I access each one and display the data ?,that is to say, enter the type on the right and the left.

This is my code:

```
open Cil_types
open Function_Froms  
(* usage: frama-c file.c -load-script print_vals.ml *)
    let aux depsReturn =
        match depsReturn with
        |Function_Froms.Memory.Top -> Locations.Zone.bottom
        |Function_Froms.Memory.Bottom -> Locations.Zone.bottom
        |Function_Froms.Memory.Map m ->  Function_Froms.Memory.fold (fun z v acc ->
            let open DepsOrUnassigned in
            match v with
    | DepsBottom | Unassigned -> acc
    | AssignedFrom _ | MaybeAssignedFrom _ -> Locations.Zone.join z acc)
      m Locations.Zone.bottom

let () =
  Db.Main.extend (fun () ->
      Format.printf "computing value...@.";
      !Db.Value.compute();
      let fun_name = "main" in
      let kf = Globals.Functions.find_by_name fun_name in
      if !Db.From.is_computed kf then
        Format.printf "Do to pass?...\n";
      let deps = !Db.From.get kf in
      let depsReturn = deps.deps_table in
      let aux1 =aux depsReturn
      in
      let aux2 =Function_Froms.Memory.substitute depsReturn in
      Format.printf " Passed \n";

    )
```

This is the result you get with -deps and below that I would like to put.

```
....
[from] ====== DEPENDENCIES COMPUTED ======
       These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
[from] Function f:
  y FROM x
  \result FROM x
[from] Function main:
  y FROM \nothing
  z FROM \nothing (and SELF)
[from] ====== END OF DEPENDENCIES ======
computing value...
Do to pass?...
 To Pass..
```

new way:

```
Function main:

sub fuction: y 

val: nothing

sub function: z

val: nothing
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far and what is not working as expected.

Comment: Do you know how to write code in OCaml ? Did you find the `From` module in file `db.mli`?

Comment: Your code does not compile because `Function_Froms.Memory.substitute` expects two arguments: a memory state (probably `deps` here), and something of type `Deps.t`, hence probably `depsReturn`. But I do not understand what you are attempting to compute, so I cannot help you further. Can you clarify your _goal_? The example is not sufficient.

Comment: I have solved the problem, thank for your time @byako